# Write a Procedure, cursor to display cars

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I have these tables:

- Car (CarID, brand, Buyprice, YearManufacture, Color)
- Client (ClientId, name, address, salary)
- Vendor (VendorID, name)
- Sale (CarID, ClientID, VendorID, SaleDate, SalePrice)

I have to write a procedure for displaying all cars. If car is of type 'Mercedes', show its purchase price and whether it is already sold or not.

This is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PD
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE Crs CURSOR FOR 
         SELECT CarID, brand, Buyprice 
         FROM Car;

    DECLARE @Carid INT;
    DECLARE @Type varchar (100);
    DECLARE @Price INT;
    DECLARE @N INT;

    OPEN Crs;

    FETCH Crs INTO @Carid, @Type, @Price;

    WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0
        IF @Type = 'MERCEDES' 
        BEGIN
            PRINT @Price;

            SELECT @N = COUNT(*)
            FROM Sale
            WHERE CarID = @Carid;

            IF @N > 0  
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'Car already sold');
            ELSE
                PRINT 'Car is sold');
            END
        END 
    END;

    CLOSE Crs;
    DEALLOCATE Crs;

END;
```

Is it correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: You need to specify the data type for all the `declare`. Example  `DECLARE @Carid INT`

Comment: Ah yes ty I forgot it

Comment: Don't use `SELECT * FROM`, specify the column you need explicitly, it is less error prone. Like in your query you have `SELECT * FROM CAR`, that will return all 5 columns from `CAR` table. But you have only specify 3 variable in `FETCH Crs INTO`

Comment: Should I add more variables or just limit the select to the 3 attributes ID, brand, price
since he said display all cars maybe it means *

Comment: you should change the `select *` to `select CarID, brand, Buyprice`. It is always better to specify the columns that you need explicitly rather than using `*` . So don't add more variable that you are not using. There are few more syntax error in your stored procedure, I would suggest you get hold of a SQL Server, input the query there and try execute it

Comment: Okay thank you! I appreciate you help

Comment: Do use spacing, indentation on your code. It helps in readability and also identify any possible syntax error.

Comment: You can look at the example MS SQL cursor at this site.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/cursor-in-sql-server/

Comment: What actually is your question? Does this work as you want it to or not? What are your desired results? I can't actually see a reason for using a cursor if you just want a list of cars plus status sold or not sold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I don't get why you would want a cursor here at all, this should just be a joined query.**

There are almost no cicumstances when a cursor is the right answer. They are slow and inefficient, and are only useful in very specific cicumstances, such as executing DDL based on system tables.

**You want a joined query like this**

```
SELECT
   c.CarID,
   c.Brand,
   c.Buyprice,
   NumOfSales = COUNT(s.CarId)
FROM Car c
LEFT JOIN Sale s ON s.CarId = c.CarId
WHERE c.Brand = 'MERCEDES'
GROUP BY
   c.CarID,
   c.Brand,
   c.Buyprice;
```

Note the `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN`, which gets you results from `Car` even when there are no results in `Sale`.